# IBM MobileFirst: Application Authenticity rejection despite the application's authentic identity?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, authenticity

IBM MobileFirst: Why does Application Authenticity reject an application despite the application's authentic identity, in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and 7.1, after the application is installed from the Apple App Store?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/19/application-authenticity-failure-ios-app-store/) post details a possible scenario which can trigger a failure where Application Authenticity will reject an application despite the application's authentic identity, in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and 7.1, after the application was installed from the Apple App Store.

**Workaround**

For MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and 7.1, use Basic Application Authenticity (with bitcode switched off).
The Basic Application Authenticity algorithm uses application metadata to generate challenges for the client. These challenges are generated in a random process which is very hard to reverse engineer/reproduce.